# Do we want accepted answers on our site to be unpinned from the top?

Tags: discussion, accepted-answer

Currently, accepted answers are always pinned at the top of the list of answers, regardless whether you sort them by "Active", "Oldest" or "Votes".[1]
Last week, Stack Overflow [stopped pinning accepted answers to the top of the list](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/411352/6002174). This has also been announced on Meta SE: [Unpinning the accepted answer from the top of the list of answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/369568/340816). This change has not been rolled out to the entire network. In the above Meta SE post, SO employee Nicolas Chabanovsky asks,

> Would you like to have the accepted answer unpinned on your site?

Do you think this change would make sense on Language Learning Stack Exchange? The advantage of this change is that the sorting of the answers will be based on what the community thinks is the best answer rather than the question owner. We should also bear in mind that on Stack Overflow before the change, any answers, including accepted ones, could become outdated due to technological developments, so an outdated accepted answer would remain pinned at the top even after more up-to-date answers had been added and received more votes. On Language Learning SE, by contrast, answers are less likely to become outdated by technological developments (unless they are about specific digital resources), so unpinning the accepted answer seems less urgent here.

[1] If you want to look for examples, here is a [list of question with at least two answers, one of which has been accepted](https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/search?q=+answers%3A2..+hasaccepted%3Atrue). The query is easy to adapt to filter questions with a higher number of answers.

---

**Update 14.09.2021**: Since [Meta SE want to collect feedback by 19 September](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/369568/340816), I have turned this question into a survey by adding two answers that people can vote on.

---

**Update 19.09.2021**: [Feedback from this site](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/369995/340816) has been posted on Meta SE. For this reason, I have removed the [featured](/questions/tagged/featured) tag from this question.

Answer (score 3):

#### No, accepted answers should stay pinned

Answer (score 1):

As you mention, it's less likely to meet an outdated answer here than in SO. So I would vote no.

Answer (score 0):

#### Yes, let's unpin accepted answers